# How to show multiple images that are aligned in the center of the body using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a JavaScript function that detects the browser in user, Now i want to be able to append to my HTML document with images corresponding to the type of browser in use. I.e. if im using chrome i want to show img1 img2 img3 and have them all aligned in the center of a body, if im using firefox than only img4 img 5 img 6 would show and so on. I am able to show one image however even if my body is set to align center the images will be left aligned.

From what i understand you can use

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = src;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

And this will append the image to your body.

So my HTML is more or less as follows.

```
<html>
   <body align="center">
        <div id='container' ></div>
        <script>
            function waitForWhichBrowser(cb) {
                var callback = cb;

                function wait() {
                    if (typeof WhichBrowser == 'undefined') 
                        window.setTimeout(wait, 100)
                    else 
                        callback();
                }
                wait();
            }
            waitForWhichBrowser(function() {
                var o = document.getElementById('container');

                try {
                //Catches the browser metadata -- Name,Version Num,Platform  
                    Browsers = new WhichBrowser({
                        useFeatures:        true,
                        detectCamouflage:   true
                    });
                var str = Browsers + " ";
                var res = str.split(" ",1); //Parse string from WhichBroswer function to isolate browser name
                //o.innerHTML = ' ' + res;
                if(res == 'Chrome'){
                var img = document.createElement("img");
                var img2 = document.createElement("img2");
                var img3 = document.createElement("img3");
                img.src = "images/img1.png";
                img2.src = "images/img2.png";
                img3.src = "images/img3.png";
                document.body.appendChild(img);
                document.body.appendChild(img2);
                document.body.appendChild(img3);
                }
                if(res == 'Firefox'){
                var img4 = document.createElement("img4");
                var img5 = document.createElement("img5");
                var img6 = document.createElement("img6");
                img4.src = "images/img4.png";
                img5.src = "images/img5.png";
                img6.src = "images/img6.png";
                document.body.appendChild(img4);
                document.body.appendChild(img5);
                document.body.appendChild(img6);
                }
                if(res == 'Internet'){
                //Do the same for internet explorer with img7 img8 img9
                } 
                //Else clause
                if(res != 'Chrome' && res!='Firefox' && res!='Internet'){
                window.location.href = "WindowsChromeDownload.htm"; //Instead of making a separate default download page for an unspecified browser I linked the else case to the chrome landing page since it's the most common browser
                }
                //When this statement was left in all browsers would redirect to the else case
                //else{ 
                //window.location.href = "WindowsDefaultDownload.htm"; 
                //}
                } catch (e) {
                    o.innerHTML = 'Error';
                }
            });     
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So my question is, 
How can i get all my images to allign center?
Is it possible to add the images to a container inside of my body instead of the body itself. For example

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
//Location where it detects browser and appends images
</script>
    <div id='display'>
    <!-- Display images from javascript here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want your images added to <div id='display'> and centered?

Comment: Yeah, but @webkit's answer worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To add and center your images #display div do this:**

first in your **js**..

```
var display = document.getElementById('display');
```

then replace your **body.append()** with this:

```
display.appendChild(img)
```

then in your **css** add this:

```
#display { text-align:center;}
```

#### extra btw:

if you wanted to make your script more efficient and readable you could rewrite your function like so:

```
waitForWhichBrowser(function() {
    var o = document.getElementById('container');
    var imgsrc = [];
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
    try {
    //Catches the browser metadata -- Name,Version Num,Platform  
        Browsers = new WhichBrowser({
            useFeatures:        true,
            detectCamouflage:   true
        });
    var str = Browsers + " ";
    var res = str.split(" ", 1); //Parse string from WhichBroswer function to isolate browser name


    if (res == 'Chrome')  imgsrc = ["images/img.png", "images/img2.png", "images/img3.png"];
    if (res == 'Firefox') imgsrc = ["images/img4.png", "images/img5.png", "images/img6.png"];
    if(res == 'Internet') imgsrc = ["images/img7.png", "images/img8.png", "images/img9.png"];
    //Else clause
    if(res != 'Chrome' && res!='Firefox' && res!='Internet'){
        window.location.href = "WindowsChromeDownload.htm"; //Instead of making a separate default download page for an unspecified browser I linked the else case to the chrome landing page since it's the most common browser
    }

     for (var i = 0; i < imgsrc.length; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = imgsrc[i];
        display.appendChild(img);
    }
    //When this statement was left in all browsers would redirect to the else case
    //else{ 
    //window.location.href = "WindowsDefaultDownload.htm"; 
    //}
    } catch (e) {
        o.innerHTML = 'Error';
    }
});
```

Comment: sure, I've edited my answer with a suggestion for your script, notice I add the image sources to an array and then just iterate over the right array according to the browser.. good luck :)

Comment: I saw that! Thanks. It does make the code look a lot cleaner.

Comment: it seems like the images are not being appended to the display div with the latest code. Iv'e updated my code in the original post. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Just text-align the container to center:

http://jsbin.com/notocube/1/edit?html,output